# Refactored names in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

There are several occasions in OP now, where the name has been changed/updated/modified(uncertainty).

Examples are:

1. Gold Roger <-> Gol D. Roger(Explained now!)
2. Reverie  <-> levely (?)
3. Raftale  <-> Laugh tale (?)

What's going on here!!!! Do the older names become obsolete? Do these changes mean that they are meant to replace previous usage of these words? Has there been any official update regarding this? or Are they just dubbing errors that are now corrected?

**Gist of the question**: Whats up with these new names???

Comment: https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Name_Variants and https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/One_Piece_Wiki:Guidebook/Page_Naming_Guidelines#Name_Spellings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old names were written in katakana. 
Pronounced in Japanese, the phonetics would sound like this:

ゴール・ディー・ロジャー >>>> Gōru Dī Rojā

レヴェリー/世界会議 >>>> Reverī

ラフテル >>>> Rafuteru

If you noticed, many of the 'L' sounds aren't replicated in Japanese speech. In this case it's replaced with 'R' sounds.

My top guess is when things were being dubbed, they decided to go with the authentic Japanese phonetics. But when they saw that the meaning behind the names and places was getting lost on their English audience, they properly 'translated' the words.  Oda always meant for some of these names to be in English, especially for things like laugh tale and what not.

I'm just glad they checked themselves when it came to Luffy's name LOL.